# Shutdown the windows mobile device from smart device application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6

I ave return below code but it is not working for shutdown. restart works fine for me.

```
[DllImport("Aygshell.dll")]
internal static extern bool ExitWindowsEx(uint uFlags, int dwReason);


private void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
     ExitWindowsEx(2, 0); // restart
     ExitWindowsEx(1, 0); // shutdown not working  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would call SetSystemPowerState with Power_Off. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa929251.aspx). Or, call with POWER_STATE_CRITICAL (which may lead to a complete shutdown). (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms920754.aspx)

Alternatively you can also use keybd_event with VK_OFF.

Both functions may not compeletely shutdown the device, this depends on the PowerManagement implementation of the OEM.